# When to reset CyclicBarrier in java multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, cyclicbarrier

I was reading `CyclicBarrier` in the following link
http://java-latte.blogspot.in/2013/10/cyclicbarrier-in-java-concurrency.html.

In the example 1, `CyclicRaceDemo.java` main method, CyclicBarrier is being reused without calling **reset** method.

I ran the example and it worked fine. So, I am wondering what's the use of `reset` method. When should it be called? Or do we need to call it at all?

Comment: link post is unusable now.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A `CyclicBarrier` is cyclic because it can be reused without resetting. From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html)

> A synchronization aid that allows a set of threads to all wait for
>   each other to reach a common barrier point. CyclicBarriers are useful
>   in programs involving a fixed sized party of threads that must
>   occasionally wait for each other. The barrier is called *cyclic* because
>   it can be re-used after the waiting threads are released.

So in normal usage, once all the threads are collected and the barrier is broken, it resets itself and can be used again.

From the [Javadoc for `reset()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html#reset())

> Resets the barrier to its initial state. If any parties are currently
>   waiting at the barrier, they will return with a
>   `BrokenBarrierException`. Note that resets after a breakage has occurred
>   for other reasons can be complicated to carry out; threads need to
>   re-synchronize in some other way, and choose one to perform the reset.
>   It may be preferable to instead create a new barrier for subsequent
>   use.

So `reset` causes any currently waiting threads to throw a `BrokenBarrierException` and wake immediately. `reset` is used when you want to "break" the barrier.

Note also the caveat - once the threads have been awoken forcibly it's tricky to synchronize them again.

**TL;DR**: you should never need to use `reset()` in normal circumstances.

Comment: What do you mean by `tricky`? It's same word which comes from the javadoc that I don't understand. Does it mean it's hard to re-synchronize the barrier when it's at the middle of handling the breakage (caused by the `reset()`), then some other threads come to it and ask for a ...barrier?