# Is there anyway to do or simulate CyclicBarrier.awaitAndReset()

Tags: java, concurrency

Is there anyway to reset the CyclicBarrier once it breaks.

I'm running the threads in loop. I feel that doing below is not really thread-safe:

```
if (cyclicBarrier.await()==0) {
   cyclicBarrier.reset()
}
```

I was hoping there is some kind of an atomic command to do it like:

```
cyclicBarrier.awaitAndReset();
```

Comment: This is a good reference for your question. Seems like reset functionality shouldn't be used in normal circumstances as it actually breaks the barrier. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104642/when-to-reset-cyclicbarrier-in-java-multithreading

CyclicBarrier can be reused without resetting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to reset CyclicBarrier in java multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104642/when-to-reset-cyclicbarrier-in-java-multithreading)

Comment: Thanks! So await() inherently does what I was hoping.

Comment: Yeah @pom that is correct...so I literally googled your "how to reset CyclicBarrier once it breaks" and that was the first answer haha so maybe try googling what you write before posting just to see :)

Comment: Okiedokie. Thanks again ;)